# How can I add payload when generating JWT in http JWT AUTH?

Tags: http, jwt, ballerina

[This](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-service-jwt-auth/) is what I could find on official ballerina learn-by-examples website.

But how can I sign payloads and return JWT on some endpoints, like we do in NodeJS using `jsonwebtoken`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`jwt:issue()` method](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/jwt/latest) to achieve this.

```
    jwt:IssuerConfig issuerConfig = {
        username: "user",
        issuer: "wso2",
        audience: "example.com",
        expTime: 3600,
        signatureConfig: {
            config: {
                keyFile: "./resources/private.key"
            }
        },
        customClaims: {
            "scope": "scope1 scope2"
        }
    };

    string jwt = check jwt:issue(issuerConfig);
```

You can refer [this service example](https://github.com/IMS94/ballerina_reactjs/blob/master/auth_service.bal) for a scenario where this approach was used to implement a login endpoint.